# Go Modules management

Tags: go, go-modules

While I try to build I am getting the following error:

```
go.mod requires settings-management-service  but vendor/modules.txt does not include it.
run 'go mod tidy; go mod vendor' to sync
```

I tried running go mod tidy; go mod vendor, but didn't help.

Comment: Is `settings-management-service` one of your deps ?

Comment: No its not one if deps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try deleting your `vendor` folder, and then running `go mod vendor` again.

If `settings-management-service` is a local dependency, check if you are importing it correctly.
The first line of your `go.mod` file should show the name of your module. Considering the name is `app`, and `settings-management-service` is a internal module, it should be imported as :

```
import "app/settings-management-service"
```

Do check if all deps are being downloaded correctly, and run `go mod download`.